# error killing pod: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for device or resource busy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

When I want to restart the kubernetes(`v1.21.2`) statefulset pod, the pod are stuck with terminating status, and the log shows like this:

```
error killing pod: failed to "KillPodSandbox" for "8aafe99f-53c1-4bec-8cb8-abd09af1448f" with KillPodSandboxError: "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to check network namespace closed: remove netns: unlinkat /var/run/netns/cni-f9ccb1de-ed43-dff6-1b86-1260e07178e6: device or resource busy"
```

the pod terminate for hours but still stuck. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think force deletion can be a workaround for this issue.

In order to delete the affected pod that is in the terminating state, please refer to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/#delete-pods). In case the pod still does not get deleted then you can do the force deletion by following [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/#force-deletion).

Please note that when you force delete a StatefulSet pod, you are asserting that the Pod in question will never again make contact with other Pods in the StatefulSet and its name can be safely freed up for a replacement to be created.

You can also try these workarounds to quickly mitigate this

1. Run the command below to remove all pods in the terminating state.

> for p in $(kubectl get pods | grep Terminating | awk '{print $1}'); do
> kubectl delete pod $p --grace-period=0 --force;done

2.Set finalizer value in the deployment YAML to null.